Implementation of the SIRD model in Python
I'm working on a project for my class where I'm trying to implement the SIRD model with the vaccinated population. I wrote my code based on my equations, but something seems wrong with my graph. The vaccinated population doesn't increase, and the recovered and deceased population become almost constant around the 80-day mark.
I don't know if the graph is supposed to turn out that way or not. Can someone help me fix my code? I'm not using odeint by the way.
The graph produced by my code:

The differential equations used in my code:

My code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sirdv
#a-alpha b-beta g-gamma d-delta m-mu e=vaccine efficacy
#N=population s(t)=susceptible d(t)=deceased i(t)=infected r(t)=recovered v(t)=vaccinated
#n=s+i+r+d+v
# ds/dt=-b/N(si) dr/dt=gi dd/dt=mi di/dt=b/N(si-gi-mi)-a*s) dv/dt=a*s-(e*b*i*v)/N
N=1000 #total population
b=0.5 # transmission rate ranged from 0.4 to 0.6
a=0.05 #5 % of susceptible population
e=0.7 #as of now 
g=1/7 # recovery rate
m=0.01 #death rate between 0.01 to 0.1 %
M=(m)/(m+g) #=fatalities/resolutions
R0=b/g
print(M)
print(R0)

steps=np.arange(0,365,dtype=int)
time=1*steps
def SIRDV(s,i,r,d,b,g,m,a,v,e):
    sdash= -s*i*(b/(s+i+r+d+v))-(a*s)
    rdash=g*i
    idash=((s*i*b)/(s+i+r+d+v))-(g*i)-(m*i)
    ddash=m*i
    vdash=(a*s)-((e*b*i*v)/(s+i+r+d+v))

    return sdash, idash, rdash, ddash, vdash

tlen=len(time)
s=np.empty([tlen])
i=np.empty([tlen])
r=np.empty([tlen])
d=np.empty([tlen])
v=np.empty([tlen])


r[0]=0
i[0]=1
d[0]=0
v[0]=0
s[0]=N-i[0]-r[0]-d[0]-v[0]

dt=0.05

for t in steps:
    if t<len(steps)-1:
        sdash, idash, rdash, ddash, vdash= SIRDV(s[t],i[t],r[t],d[t],v[t],b,g,m,e,a)
        s[t+1]=s[t]+dt*sdash
        i[t+1]=i[t]+dt*idash
        r[t+1]=r[t]+dt*rdash
        d[t+1]=d[t]+dt*ddash
        v[t+1]=v[t]+dt*vdash


plt.plot(time,s,label='susceptible')
plt.plot(time,i,label='infected')
plt.plot(time,r,label='recovered')
plt.plot(time,d,label='deceased')
plt.plot(time,v,label='vaccinated')
plt.xlabel('time in days')
plt.ylabel('no of people')
plt.legend()
plt.pause(0.01)
plt.show()

My code is simple, so I have no idea, what's wrong.

Looks fine to me. The number of vaccinated people isn't increasing anymore because everyone is either recovered, dead, or already vaccinated. And people aren't dying for the same reason.

What is the point of your if in your for loop?

SIRDV(s[t],i[t],r[t],d[t],v[t],b,g,m,e,a) is not in the same order as SIRDV(s,i,r,d,b,g,m,a,v,e), so v[t] becomes b, e becomes v, etc. Is that intentional?
